# How to assign two values to two columns using one lambda sentence in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a function which returns two values like:

```
def myfunc(x):
   return a, b
```

And I want to assign a and b to two columns in my dataset, currently I use code like:

```
df.loc[:,'col1'] = df['col0'].apply(lambda x: myfunc(x)[0])
df.loc[:,'col2'] = df['col0'].apply(lambda x: myfunc(x)[1])
```

Certainly it's inefficient because it calls `myfunc` twice. But I don't know how to assign values to two columns using one sentence in this circumstance.

Comment: have you tried `df[['col1','col2']] = df['col0'].apply(lambda x: myfunc(x))` ?

Comment: `data2 = data['col'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'col1': x**2, 'col2': x+2})) `works too

Comment: It returns an error:  ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Comment: data2 = data['col'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'col1': x**2, 'col2': x+2}))  works but it doesn't solve the problem. It still calls myfunc twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert the function output to Series:

```
def myfunc(x):
    # dummy example
    return x+1, x**2

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1,2,3,4]})
df[['col2', 'col3']] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(myfunc(x)))
```

*NB. this kind of operation is **slow**, better find a way to make your function vectorial*

output:

```
   col  col2  col3
0    1     2     1
1    2     3     4
2    3     4     9
3    4     5    16
```

Alternatively, this might be slightly more efficient as the dataframe constructor is called only once (vs one Series per row above):

```
df[['col2', 'col3']] = pd.DataFrame(zip(*df['col'].apply(myfunc))).T
```